# Python merge element of the list

Tags: python

I'd like to get from this list of list:

```
[[a,10],[b,3],[c,4],[a,6],[d,11],[c,6],[a,7],[d,10]]
```

this:

```
[[a,10,6,7][b,3][c,4,6][d,11,10]]
```

thanks

Comment: What's the logic you want to implement?

Comment: I have tried in various ways, with groupby etc.
I'm doing exercises for an exam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to preserve the order of the first elements, something like this might work:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def merge(seq):
    d = OrderedDict()
    for k,v in seq:
        d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
    result = [[k]+v for k,v in d.iteritems()]
    return result
```

This loops over each pair in the sequence.  For each `k`, we either get the list associated with it in the dictionary `d` (if we've already seen it) or make a new empty list and get that.  (That's what `setdefault` does.)  In either case we append `v` to that list.  Finally we loop over every key, value pair in our dictionary `d` and make a new list in the form you want.  Example:

```
>>> s = [['a',10],['b',3],['c',4],['a',6],['d',11],['c',6],['a',7],['d',10]]
>>> merge(s)
[['a', 10, 6, 7], ['b', 3], ['c', 4, 6], ['d', 11, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that doesn't require importing:

```
>>> lis = [['a',10],['b',3],['c',4],['a',6],['d',11],['c',6],['a',7],['d',10]]
>>> dct = {a:[] for a,_ in lis}
>>> for b,c in lis: dct[b]+=[c]
...
>>> sorted([[d]+e for d,e in dct.items()])
[['a', 10, 6, 7], ['b', 3], ['c', 4, 6], ['d', 11, 10]]
>>>
```